# Capture new browser window open event with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

is it possible to capture new browser window open event with javascriptand call some functions before? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

`window` doesn't have a `beforeload` event.

Something like this could work, but keep in mind that overriding window.open is pretty dangerous.

```
var windowOpen = window.open;

window.open = function(url, name, features, replace) {
    alert("opening a window");
    // do other stuff here
    windowOpen(url, name, features, replace);  
}

window.open("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: could you elaborate the bad consequences of overriding window.open()?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to override window (or most global) functions because your overridden implementation is likely more error-prone and could produce unintended side-effects for other code relying on window.open.

A better strategy is usually to provide a new function that calls window.open AND does whatever else you want window.open to do, and use that in your own code. This way, only code calling your method is affected.

Comment: it just saved my day!! i don't know why it's not marked as correct answer but tq buddy!